# SQL query to get all repeated entries

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I've got a table with `id` (int) and `sell_date` (datetime). These are client `id` and date of selling. I have to get count of clients, who are bought something at least 2 times in month, group by `DATE_FORMAT(sell_date,'%Y-%m') AS period`.

For example: i've got client with id=1. He bought something 1 time in 01-2014, 2 times in 02-2014 and 3 times in 03-2014. So i want to get this:

```
period  |repeated_buyers

2014-01 | (none)
2014-02 | 1
2014-03 | 1
```

I'm bad as SQL. Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. You need to do a `group by` on the date

```
select DATE_FORMAT(sell_date,'%Y-%m') AS period,
Count(*) as repeated_buyers
from sales
group by DATE_FORMAT(sell_date,'%Y-%m')
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select DATE_FORMAT(sell_date,'%Y-%m') AS period,COUNT(ID) as repeated_buyers
from MyTable 
GROUP BY ID,DATE_FORMAT(sell_date,'%Y-%m')
having COUNT(ID)>=2
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I did it!

```
    SELECT `period`, 
count(`id`) as `accounts`
    FROM (SELECT 
DATE_FORMAT(`sell_date`,'%Y-%m') AS `period`, 
`id` FROM `terst` GROUP BY `period`, `id` HAVING COUNT(`id`)>1 )A
    GROUP BY `period`
```

Answer (score 0):

try below sql query,

```
select id,period,repeated_buyers from(select DATE_FORMAT(sell_date,'%Y-%m') AS period,id,
Count(*) as repeated_buyers
from TABLE1
group by  DATE_FORMAT(sell_date,'%Y-%m'),id) where repeated_buyers>=2;
```

Comment: Mind to [explain your solution](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) a bit?

Comment: Hi. Here inner query returns period,id and buyers count in perticular month. To get details of buyers who bought atleat 2 times in a month, writing outer query to filter the results coming from inner query by placing >=2 condition.